# VBA code to select specific cell and paste down accordingly

Tags: vba, excel

I want to select specific cells from all the worksheets present in my Excel workbook and then paste in a master sheet. Problem is I am not getting that from the code created, I get an error but if I leave it as it is right now (shown below) I get it for a specific cell and then I have to go into the code to change the cell and where I want it outputted to. I apologize in advance for my naivety.

As it is right now

```
Sub CopyIt()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If ws.Name <> "Masters" Then
            ws.Range("B18").Copy Sheets("Masters").Cells(Rows.Count, "Q").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
        End If
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

I want this cell range `"B2-B18"` to be copied to `"A:Q"` and in the master sheet. So values in B2 go to `A` column and so on and so and then at the end `B18` goes to `Q`.

What did I not do for the code to do what it should?

Comment: So you want the range B2 to B18 in sheet A to go to A1-Q1 in the Master sheet, and cycle through all sheets doing this, am I correct?

Comment: Yes you are correct. actually A2:Q2. I am using Excel 2013.

Answer (score 1):

Hey I just tested this and it should do the trick for you

```
Sub CopyIt()

Dim pasteRow As Integer
Dim ws As Worksheet
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

pasteRow = 2

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If ws.Name <> "Masters" Then
        ws.Range("B2", "B18").Copy
        Sheets("Masters").Range("A" & pasteRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
        False, Transpose:=True

        pasteRow = pasteRow + 1
    End If

Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

This will advance a row for each worksheet so you can add as many worksheets as you like.  Note that this really isn't the most universal code, you would need to change the `ws.Range("B2", "B18").copy` to something that would select say, all ranges in a column or you will have to manually expand the range each time you want to change it.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
ws.Range("B1:B18").Copy 
Sheets("Masters").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=True
```

That should copy B1:B18, transpose it from columns to rows and paste it in the last row in Column A of your Masters sheet.

Comment: Run-time error 438, Object doesn't support this property or method. Thats what I got. I'm using excel 2013

Answer (score 0):

enable developer toolbar
select record a macro
select b2:b18 in a one sheet select another sheet and right click paste special all and also select transpose
stop recording macro
now edit the macro to suit your requirements

a sample macro autogenerated code as follows

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'

'
    Range("B2:B18").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
        False, Transpose:=True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the required...
(This will copy paste values from B2:B18 cells in each sheet to different rows in the Sheet "Masters")

Sub Macro1()

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim row_count As Integer
row_count = 1

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    MsgBox ws.name
    If ws.name <> "Masters" Then
        ws.Activate
        Range("B2:B18").Select
        Selection.Copy
        Sheets("Masters").Activate
        Range("A" & row_count).Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
            False, Transpose:=True
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        row_count = row_count + 1
    End If
Next
```

End Sub